# What is the meaning of the Bencher.bytes?

Tags: rust, benchmarking

I found [this benchmark code](https://rust-malaysia.github.io/code/2020/07/11/faster-integer-parsing.html):

```
#[bench]
fn bench_str_parse(b: &mut Bencher) {
    assert_eq!(str_parse(EXAMPLE_TIMESTAMP), EXPECTED_TIMESTAMP);
    b.bytes = EXAMPLE_TIMESTAMP.len() as u64;
    b.iter(|| str_parse(black_box(EXAMPLE_TIMESTAMP)));
}
```

The code assigns a number to `b.bytes`, with `b` having the type `test::Bencher`.  What is the meaning of that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is means of the "Bencher.bytes" ?

If the concept of throughput is relevant to what you're benching (which is the case for parsing strings, to an extent) you can set the `bencher.bytes` field to the amount of data used / consumed per iteration, and at the end the benchmark report will print a throughput in bytes/second or somesuch.